# Setting div height not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am writing a script that uses some absolutely positioned elements in multiple full page height elements on a single page website. On a mobile view, this page is obviously larger than the viewport so I am using JQuery to resize the parent. This works fine on most devices but on others, the height of the parent does not expand.

The HTML for each page starts like this and there are four instances of this on the entire page:

```js
function em(input) {
  var emSize = parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
  var em = emSize * input;
  return em;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.page').each(function() {
    $(this).css('height', $(this).children('.stuff').outerHeight() + 30 + em(4));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="services" class="page">
  <div class="image" data-type="background"></div>
  <div class="container stuff">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The biggest I am having is with the iPhone 5, it looks right on all other devices that I have tried. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Let me explain the website a little better. So I have a single page website with multiple sections (pages) in it, each one has a minimum height of 100vh. Several of them, depending on the size of the screen, are larger than 100vh and overlap the next section (page). I am trying to use the JQuery above to resize the page so this does not happen. It works on most devices, but not on others, specifically the iPhone 5.

Comment: What is `em()`? Does that represent an `em` unit? I haven't seen that before. Have you tried `$(this).css('height', 'calc(' + parseInt($(this).children('.stuff').outerHeight() + 30) + 'px + 4em)');`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain that. The em is a function that converts the number into an em unit. `function em(input) {
    var emSize = parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
    var em = emSize * input;
 return em;
}`

Comment: Are you just trying to set each page's height equal to the viewport height? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here

Comment: No, I already have that. When the absolutely positioned elements inside of the page are longer than the page, I need to resize the page to fit it.